# What is Norman Bates’ skeletal apparition in the final scene of Psycho?

Tags: movie, psycho

In the final scene of the Alfred Hitchcock thriller, *[Psycho](https://youtu.be/dYDxxHrlmUg)*, just before the final cut to “The End,” the camera focuses on Norman Bates’ face.

For a split second, a ghoulish visage of a skeletal form manifests as part of Norman’s form — this appears to be either that we’re able to see Norman’s own skeleton, his teeth, skull, etc. through his skin, or this is some sort of apparition perhaps that is possessing him. The out-of-universe effect is a composite superposition of film: frames of Anthony Perkins were overlaid with those of a matching skeleton.

Until this point in the movie, there are generally no other strange or supernatural elements; it is simply physical slasher “horror” — a whodunit mystery.

But with the final scene, and the appearance of a skeletal form superimposed over Bates, is there some fantasy or supernatural element beyond Norman’s mental illness, which lies at the root of Norman’s murderous spree? Interested primarily in authoritative source, if that exists.

Comment: This can be considered "science fiction" because it hinges on a "finding" of "science". No matter what we think of this aspect of psychology now, it was accepted then.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Spencer wouldn't that make it real world science then? If it was an accepted condition of phycology back in the day then there is nothing about it that is "fiction".

Comment: @skooba What is explanation (assuming answer below is authoritative), for seeing the actual corpse of Norman’s mother in this manner? I’m not imagining it; this is a designed film special effect to generate this image. Are you normally seeing decomposed corpses merged with people in your life and so think that is normal, non-fantastical condition?

Comment: @skooba This is simply too-broad an interpretation of the "real-world science" concept.

Comment: It's a special effect put in by the director, who was worried no one would catch the many subtle hints that it's Mother who is in charge now

Comment: Although, like Spencer, I don't think Hitchcock intended to portray anything supernatural, I think the question is still on-topic. It's much more common over the last few decades for films to employ special effects in an attempt to create [realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realism_(arts)#Cinema), rather than the symbolic thing that's presumably going on here. (Is symbolic the right word?) For someone used to special effect realism, this might well make them think wait, what, he has a skeleton face now?

Comment: @fez do you have source? That’s what I’m actually interested in knowing, especially if Hitchcock confirmed it.

Comment: @Silly but True - You're unlikely to find a quote offering the confirmation you're looking for from the director. He certainly wouldn't have said anything like that around the film's release, as Norman being the killer was supposed to be a huge twist. Having watched all the films in the series though, I can tell you that there's nothing supernatural in any of the sequels.

Answer (score 10):

There is no "skeletal apparition".  What you are seeing is a superimposition of Norman's mother's partially-decomposed, mummified face on Norman's.  This illustrates that the "mother" personality has taken over Norman's DID afflicted mind. [This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49QFFiPb9VQ) contains a good analysis. A psychiatrist discusses this in the scene right before the clip you linked to.

If you look closely, you can see the woman's hairline, forehead wrinkles and eyes, just below Norman's:

[image: Mother inside Norman]

The teeth suggest "Mother's" smug grin, confident that she will get away with the murders and Norman will be blamed.

Just before the fade-in, you can see young Norman's unwrinkled forehead:

[image: Just Norman]

Comment: Not one but _two_ downvotes. Care to comment?

Comment: I downvoted because this question is clearly and obviously off-topic and by answering it, you've encouraged the *future asking* of questions that are clearly and obviously off-topic.

Comment: @Valorum Again, I do not see it that way; it is more of an edge case to me.

Comment: @Valorum, the question may be off-topic, but this is a very good answer.  Informative and accurate, almost certainly the correct answer. Downvote and close the question, by all means.  This answer deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Pete - If anything, that makes it worse. If people can get high quality answers to blatantly off-topic questions, they'll deluge the site with them.